# "How to avoid GVim treating <M-h> like è ?" or "Is there a way for saying to GVim to use escape sequences for meta modifier?"?

Tags: vim

Context:

`set encoding=utf-8`

If I type:

`:imap <M-h> foo`

then I type

`:imap <M-h>`

I get:

`i  è             foo`

and, as result, both `<M-h>` and `è`, if pressed in insert mode, insert `foo`

I tested this behavior both on Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP

Linking to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim), seems that GVim treats the Meta key adding `0x80` to the keycode.
Reading the previous linked answer and googleing I thought it might be only a matter for terminal Vim, not for GVim.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't possible today, even in GVIM. Even worse, some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.