# Vim insert strange characters when trying to fix Alt key

Tags: vim, terminal

I found the workaround for mapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on gnome-terminal in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim.). After editing the `vimrc` file, my Vim now recognizes <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> as `ê` (which is a non-english character), how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the referenced topic, for Vim, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *character* combinations are represented by ASCII characters with the 8th bit set, which is identical to certain special characters (such as `ê`). As long as you don't need to type those characters (e.g. because you write in French :-), you can ignore this curiosity; just write your mapping with either `<A-j>` or the literal `ê` notation (but after any `:set encoding=...` in your .vimrc, because that affects how these are interpreted).

Comment: I tried to map <A-J> gg but it doesnt work, while map <C-j> gg still work well.

Comment: @navie strange, it does work here. On your question you mentioned `<A-j>`, but you said `<A-J>` on your comment; is there any chance that you mapped uppercase (`J`) and tested with lowercase (`j`)?

Comment: I second @mMontu's suggestion: For Alt mappings, the case of the character _does_ matter (for Ctrl it does not, because Vim cannot differentiate shifted chars there). So `<A-J>` is really `<A-S-j>`.

Comment: Be sure that you aren't changing you encoding, as pointed out in the answer, after setting up the mapping (like in your gvimrc).  I ran into that myself recently and it caused some consternation.

Comment: Thanks Ingo Karkat amd mMontu, I actually got both the encoding and Upper case problems :P