# vim - when triggering a macro, normal mode isn't switched from insert mode (xterm)

Tags: vim, terminal, macros

For testing purpose I created simple macro which wraps current line into single quotes and goes to next line.

Here is output from the register the macro is saved in: `I'^[A'^[j`
And here is testing text:
`Line number 1 
 Line number 2`

if I trigger the macro on the line number 1, cursor position should be changed to the line number 2 and the text should be changed to:

`'Line number 1' 
 Line number 2{CURSOR_POSITION}`

Instead of the expected result, vim stays in insert mode at the end of line 1 and result is following:

`'Line number 1'ê{CURSOR_POSITION}
 Line number 2`

...where `{CURSOR_POSITION}` is current cursor position

Why vim place `ê` character at the end of first line and doesn't go to the next line?

I got same result when I ran vim with `--noplugin` option.
I use `xterm-256color`
Vim 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a bug (discussion [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2017)). I know it is stupid but this should work :-)

```
I'^[A'^[1j
```

It is because `^[j` can be interpreted as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14557599/5154907)).