# Mapping Alt-j and Alt-k in vim

Tags: vim

So I have this in my `.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <A-j> 5j
nnoremap <A-k> 5k
```

What I expected this to do was allow me to press Alt+j / Alt+k in order to move up and down 5 lines at a time, or use `5<A-j>` to move 25 lines down (5 * 5 = 25). Instead, it does nothing at all. Could anyone let me know what I've done wrong here?

**EDIT:** I've solved this by using the code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216459/2061838

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7501242/778118.  Your commands work for me, so it might have something to do with your terminal settings (like some of these answers/comments mention).

Comment: I've tried disabling alt activating menu items in my terminal, with no luck. I don't exactly understand what the answer involving "C-V" in that question is asking me to do, although it seems relevant.

Comment: You can press `CTRL-V` to indicate that the next character you enter will be a _control sequence_.  For example, if you want to search for all the `CTRL-M` characters in a file (newline characters from a PC) you would enter `/` (to search) followed by `CTRL-V` `CTRL-M`.  When you do this, you'll see a little `^M` character appear as your search phrase.  That answer is saying that you should go to your .vimrc file and type `CTRL-V` `ALT-j` to see what the output is.

Comment: in termial or gvim? I guess terminal right?

Comment: Either or... Try opening your `.vimrc` file with either and entering the map command while using `CTRL-V` `ALT-j`.

Comment: Actually, I've found that adding the code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10216459/2061838 solved the problem entirely. Thanks for the info though, I wasn't aware of those things.

Comment: Excellent.  Make sure you upvoted that answer if it helped.  It looks like a good one!  I'll also just throw in that `CTRL-U` and `CTRL-D` are _page up_ and _page down_ in vim, respectively.