# How can I change vim mappings for accented characters

Tags: vim, mapping, key-bindings

I am trying to change vim mappings for (french) accentuated characters.

`à` (ASCII 133) I would like it to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
`À` (ASCII 183) I would like it to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
`é` (ASCII 130) I would like it to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>
`É` (ASCII 144) I would like it to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

I would be happy to remap the existing maps <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> ==> `é` (why is that?)
How can I get those mappings to work ?

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: I am using a qwerty keyboard

Comment: no... http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm

Comment: +1 @progo. ASCII is 7-bit, from 0 - 127. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii. There are 8-bit extensions, sometimes called 8-bit ASCII or extended ASCII, but the characters with the upper-bit set aren't defined consistently. Compare ISO-8859-1, Win-1252 and ASCII. That chart shows ASCII as "ASCII-I" and what it calls "ASCII-II" are characters with the upper-bit set, AKA, "extended".

Comment: Relevant: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (also includes info about ascii, obviously).

Comment: sorry but any idea about the question itself ?

Comment: At a guess, Alt-i maps to é instead of í because alt-e is already mapped to open the edit menu, and so it couldn't be used for é. And rightly or wrongly, someone felt it was more important to have é than í.

Answer (score 2):

mapping works for theses chars, and the question is about the alt key, which may not work when the terminal prefixes the character with an ESC character. type `:help map-alt-keys` for more informations on that.

I just tried in xterm and theses mapping worked:

```
:imap <A-a> à
:imap <A-A> À
:imap <A-e> é
:imap <A-E> É
```

And also, for changing default mapping to another, use "remap" instead of map :

```
:iremap <A-i> whatever
```

Edit : see also [Alt key shortcuts not working on gnome terminal with Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim)

Comment: How about the other way around? I am trying to map combinations with the accented keys to something else, without success. For example, how would you map `<c-à>` ?

Comment: @Tropilio currently I'm using `Qwerty Lafayette` layout, which is great to use to code with vim and to write properly in french, and have no more accented key in direct access. But I m surprised the other way doesn't work. Maybe it's depends of the filetype or encoding you use for your .vimrc