# vimrc key mapping not working after the Esc key

Tags: vim, keymapping

```
map <Alt>q <Esc>la
```

This line in my vimrc seems not working after the Esc key. It do exits the insert mode but doesn't enter insert mode again. I also tried

```
inoremap <Alt>q <Esc>la
map <Alt>q <Esc><Ctrl-A>
map <Alt>q <Esc><Ctrl>A
```

Basically I want to have something within the normal typing position to have the same effect as  key. Say

```
(i>5[cursor]) 
->
(i>5)[cursor]
```

Solution:

I figured out the problem. Its cuz my terminal doesn't properly recognize alt as the alt, instead as a system level alt somehow. see

[Alt key shortcuts not working on gnome terminal with Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see there are two problems:

1. `<Alt>` isn't a thing. If you want to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, that's `<M-q>`.
2. `:map` doesn't apply to insert mode.

You haven't explained what you're trying to do, so I can't tell you what to do instead.

Comment: thanks! It worked after some inspiration from you! Although not the exact problem but helped :)