# Vim mapping error. Mapping of <A-j> leads to mapping in ë in ubuntu 19.10 eoan

Tags: ubuntu, vim, plugins, keyboard, mapping

Click on the link below to see the ScreenPrint. You can observe the result of `:map` in the lower terminal, and my .vimrc on the right one

I only have two NERDTree plugins, so I highly doubt it's caused by internal keymapping conflicts. I don't have the alt key mapped to anything else. And I am doing it exactly as in the documentation `:h alt`

[image: ScreenPrint of Mappings and .vimrc]

I already checked my Ubuntu default `Keyboard Shortcuts` in `Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

I would be happy if anyone gave me a hand on this

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216459/10803131).

Long story short, vim expects alt-keys to sent in one form, but most terminals, such as gnome terminal which I assume you're using, send them in another form. There is no good way to change this. With terminal vim I decided just to not use them. You can successfully get the map to work, but you will have to deal with overlapping mappings, timeout issues, and broken macros/plugins which have no solution other than to simply not use certain functionality.