# How to set correctly alt + key as keycodes in vim?

Tags: vim

I have struggles binding the `<m-key>` combination. I tried the solution suggested here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216459/1745291

```
  let c='a'
  while c <= 'z'
    exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
    exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
    let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
  endw
  set ttimeout ttimeoutlen=5
```

However, the `^[j` combination for `<m-j>` (for example) is always triggered even if I wait more than `ttimeoutlen` between `<esc>` and `j`. What I mean is that when I bind `<m-j>`, then vim binds it as two keycodes (that times out after `timeoutlen`) instead as one (that would time out after `ttimeout`).

How can I configure the `^[j` as a single keycode instead as a sequence ?